# CSS is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and I am converting html template to `wordpress`. I have included all css files in functions file but css is not working. All css files are in css folder. Below is the code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($content_width)){
$content_width = 660;}
function softech_setup(){
add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
add_theme_support('title-tag');}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'softech_setup');
function softech_scripts(){ 
/*Add Styles*/
wp_enqueue_style('all-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.css');
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
wp_enqueue_style('animate-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css');
wp_enqueue_style('color-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/color/color.css');
wp_enqueue_style('settings-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rs-plugin/css/settings.css.css');

/*Add Scripts*/
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-1.11.3.min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.main.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-plugins-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/plugins.main.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-themepunch.tools-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-themepunch.revolution-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts ', 'softech_scripts');
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked if it is loaded ?

Comment: its not loading. i don't know what is the problem

Comment: try to register one script and enque all other with that.

Comment: To solve the CSS issues you have to inspect the generated code with the browsers debugger, there is not much we can do to help you there. There is another issue with the scripts you are loading: In every script you provide 'jquery' as dependency. This loads the jQuery that ships with WordPress. Additionally, you are loading your own jQuery, so it will be loaded twice. This will create problems. And last, the scripts you load will not work with the jQuery from WordPress due to it's [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider its not showing css in browser debugger.

Comment: There is a blank at the endof the hook: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts ', 'softech_scripts');`. Is this a typo in the question or also in your actual code?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes, space was in the code, i have removed but still there is problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you correctly include the following functions:

**1. in header.php**

```
<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

**2. in page.php, single.php, home.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**3. In footer.php (before the `</body></html>` tag)**

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Your page source.

Rightclick -> Goto-> view page source.

In page source check your  style sheet url.

Comment: i just saw in view source that path is different

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Softech/style.css/css/all.css?ver=4.4

can you please guide how to unlink (style.css)
i couldn't figure out

Comment: which theme your are using parent theme or child theme, ...your theme name is correct?

Comment: Hi,Now you fixed or not

Answer (score 0):

use `get_stylesheet_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Maybe you could add some information why this would be a solution for the problem?

Comment: @user2055788  it is not because of this function, if it would have the problem , it should show url which will be having no file, he is getting nothing on source code that means , it is not enqued not incorrect url.

Answer (score 0):

Try the wp_register_style function.
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

```
wp_register_style('all-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.css');

wp_enqueue_style('all-css');
```